# Google App script - update row according to criteria (based on condition)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to automate a task that is below -

1. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AcYFOhs6XQHwhrToRaUau56I0XISEocGWmfqufH-acc/edit?usp=sharing (From here)
2. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dQiX1MOlDTnAkXKbk2AA-ojhThHbqqp_sXQhvNltCJk/edit?usp=sharing (To there)

These are the sample datasets that I'm using.

So the "From here" Google Sheet data gets updated every once a week from system A1 in "From here".
G sheet also gets updated when week # changes

I would like to append values in "From here" to "To here" G sheet data according to the conditions below..

- If A1 matches WK# (Column B) in "To There" data, then fill in A,B,C,D for columns TS, TC, TD (in "To there" G sheet) accordingly
- Additionally, I would need these actions without embedding the formulas into each cell (there will be many users that use this google sheet (To here), so formulas shouldn't be shown in the cell

So, writing a formula in the cell isn't the ideal option in this case

Would there be any optimal way of accomplishing this task in Google Sheets using Apps Script? (Maybe on Open option?) or using Google Sheets Query?

- @Tedinoz, I just edited the question!

So there is now "To There" Gsheet with the updated link

basically the successful outcome is the yellow highlighted cells in "To There"

The week gets updated by me, not by the system - whenever week changes, I will update this in cell A1

So Below is what I tried

```
function vl() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1dQiX1MOlDTnAkXKbk2AA-ojhThHbqqp_sXQhvNltCJk");
  var range1 = sheet1.getRange("A:A1"); 
  var range1a = sheet1.getRange("A2:A5")
  var range2 = sheet2.getRange("A1:E200");
  var values1 = range1.getValues();
  var values1a = range1a.getValues();
  var values2 = range2.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < values1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < values2.length; j++) {
      if (values1[i][0] === values2[j][1]) {
        values1[i][1] = values2[j][2]
        Logger.log(values1)
      }
    }
  }
```

My main struggle is on

a) how to look up based on two criteria, which is "A1" in "From Here" sheet +
   "A2:A5" in "From here" sheet (It will have to be if "AND" statements...)

b) after finding the matching values based on the above criteria, how would I move them onto "To There" rows accordingly..? I was thinking to use getRange().SetValues() method, but this does not seem right approach in this case..as it has to set values based on the matching criteria

Comment: You should post any code you've tried, just requesting people to write it for you is generally frowned upon in Stack Overflow. You should take a look at [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) on working with Apps Script and Sheets. To answer your question, you can use Apps Script to reference both sheets using `SpreadsheetApp.openById()`, then get the data with `Sheet.getRange()` and work with the Sheet's data to compare and check what you want. When you have some code you can update your question and we will be happy to help you.

Comment: Some guesses: Query?: maybe, but its just another formula (which you say you don't want). Script?: probably. Trigger?: onOpen - no, probably a timed trigger.

Comment: 1) Two spreadsheets are referenced but the link is the same, 2) No week number in Column B, 3) Content is 100% data - no formula, 4) No mention of when/how the external system updates, nor when/how the week# changes. You have outlined an interesting scenario but provided little real information. Please re-read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please edit your question to provide more information, and populate your spreadsheets with some data and show an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: @ Tedinoz, Apologies for the delay, I just edited the question!!

Comment: Since "From Here" only shows the data for the current week, a function (including "Query") would not unsuitable because prior-week data would not be retained on "To There". A script would be the best course. Then, the question of when and how to trigger it: 1) an `onEdit` trigger would be an option IF the data in the "From Here" sheet was updated before the week number was changed; but if the week number is changed first, then the script would just copy over last week's data. An alternative is a custom menu option. Which option is best depends on how/when you want the data to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

You want to copy a range of four rows from the active spreadsheet (sheet = "FromHere") to another spreadsheet (sheet = "ToThere"). The relationship between the two sheets is based on the Week Number in cell A1 of "ToThere" and which also appears in contiguous cells in Column B of "ToThere".

You suggest that there are two criteria which would require an "AND" operator. However, there is only one criteria - the week number - and the task is to identify the first occurence of the matching week number in Column B of "ToThere".

The overall process is:
1 - find a match for the Week Number on "ToThere"

- I used the Javascript method `indexOf` to find a match of the Week Number. `indexOf` returns the first index at which a given element can be found in an array, or -1 if it is not present. This required:

  - `var weekvalue = weekrange.getValue();` - get the Week Number from cell A1 of "FromHere"
  - `var ThereWeeks = ThereWeeksRange.getValues();` - get the values in the 2D array for Column B of "ToThere"
  - `var merged = ThereWeeks.reduce(function(a, b){return a.concat(b);});` - "flatten" the array to make it easier to find values
  - `var idx = merged.indexOf(weekvalue);` - find the first instance of the Week Number in Column B.

2) copy the values from "FromHere"

- `var weekdata = range1a.getValues();` - note this is the range "B2:D5".

3) copy the values to "ToThere"

- `var weektarget = sheet2.getRange((+idx+1),3,4,3);` - get the range on "ToThere"
- `weektarget.setValues(weekdata);` - update the value from "FromHere"

I have left several "Logger" statements in the code so that you can establish key values at critical points in the code.

---

```
function so5810174601() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1irUNEahhm1RM1LrpBR5d1SV1XPqwtdEhNkFu4E3meA4");
  var sheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("Sheet2");

  // get the Week Number
  var weekrange = sheet1.getRange("A1"); 
  var weekvalue = weekrange.getValue();

  // get the week data 
  var range1a = sheet1.getRange("B2:D5")
  var weekdata = range1a.getValues();

  // get the values in Column B of "ToThere"     
  // get the last row
  var sheet2LR = sheet2.getLastRow();
  // define the range from row 1, Column 2(B), down to the last Row
  var ThereWeeksRange = sheet2.getRange(1,2,sheet2LR);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: ThereWeeksRange = "+ThereWeeksRange.getA1Notation());
  // get the values
  var ThereWeeks = ThereWeeksRange.getValues();
  // Logger.log(ThereWeeks); //DEBUG
  // flatten the 2D array
  var merged = ThereWeeks.reduce(function(a, b){return a.concat(b);});
  // find the first instance of the week Number in Column B
  var idx = merged.indexOf(weekvalue);
  // as long as the result isnt -1 (no match)
  if (idx !=-1){
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: the target row = "+(+idx+1));
    // define the target range as row = index plus 1 (the index is zero based), Column = 3 (C), rows = 4 (A,B,C & D), and Columns = 3 (TS,TC,TD)
    var weektarget = sheet2.getRange((+idx+1),3,4,3);
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the sheet2 target range = "+weektarget.getA1Notation());
    // update the range on "ToThere from the range on "FromHere"
    weektarget.setValues(weekdata);
  }
  else{
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var response = ui.alert('Update Week Data', 'Could not find week number on "ToThere". Aborting.', ui.ButtonSet.YES);
  }
}
```